# Xcode Playground crashing with non-swift code

Tags: python, xcode, macos, swift, swift-playground

I tried to use Xcode's Playground feature to play around with a bit of new Javascript and Python tricks I started to learn.

Unfortunately, whenever I switch the Syntax Coloring (Editor>Syntax Coloring) to a language other then Swift, I type in the first command and the Xcode crashes.

Anyone tackled this?

P.S
after a bit of research I found out I may be quite dumb.

Is PlayGround Solely for Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Playgrounds only supports `swift`. Playground can only compile `Swift` code.